# Sort by distance in Nominatim API

Tags: flutter, sorting, search, openstreetmap, nominatim

I have developed a flutter application which uses **[Nominatim API](https://nominatim.org)** for searching on a map in **OpenStreetMap**. I have successfully implemented the search however I want the search to prioritise locations near the location that the user is currently viewing.

For Example: If the user is hovering over California, and searches for Hospitals, it should give results on hospitals near me. Currently, it gives locations that are in some other country based on their own importance settings.

Could anybody help me how to do that?

**EDIT:** I want the results to be "sorted by distance" and not "limit search to nearby locations".

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/openstreetmap/trac-tickets/issues/2519#issuecomment-885746345) you can actually add "near XYZ" to the query and get the desired results. But be aware to not use arbitrary user input in the URL, it may be malicious. For example, only use `(Lat, Long)` which are only floats. If you actually want to sort these results by distance, I think you have to calculate the distances from the coordinates.

Comment: I just tried doing this through [this link](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&q=Daffodils%20English%20School&format=json&near=77.5789482,13.0348455) with different co-ordinates, the order in which it's presented don't seem to change.

Comment: Do not use `near` as a query parameter, use it in the `q` parameter, [like so](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?addressdetails=1&q=Daffodils%20English%20School%20near%2013.0348455,77.5789482&format=json)

Comment: Thanks a lot. That actually works for places that are actually near to the location like you said. But, if I type in **Statue of Liberty** near the same co-ordinates, the API doesn't return anything because it's obviously very far away place. But I do not want such a response. I want it to return the actual Statue of Liberty as well, regardless of the distance. So what I'm looking for more specifically is an already "sorted by distance" response instead of "limiting the search to nearby places"

Comment: An example of such an API call would be the one from [photon.komoot](https://photon.komoot.io) under the "Search with priority to a geo position". That actually sorts the places and returns me the locations as I need. However, that API is not trustworthy since I get all sorts of HandShake errors and server down issues all the time, that's why I migrated to Nominatim which is amazing. But this one feature is not something I have found yet.

Comment: I do not think the API offers something like that out of the box. Have a look at the OpenStreetMap Help, there are similar questions to yours, like [this](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/65004/getting-hospitals-near-gps-coordinates-via-nominatim-is-returning-unexpected-results/65009). Seems like you need to use the Overpass-API.